# How to log response from upstream server in Apache reverse proxy?

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, iis-7.5

I have Apache with mod_proxy setup as a reverse proxy above IIS. Not matter what I do I get Proxy Error - Invalid response from upstream server error.

I have set the timeouts to 2400 seconds still errors. I am hitting IIS directly for debugging and everything works fine there. So this is not issue with IIS.

I think the only way to debug now is to log what response Apache is getting from IIS. How can I enable this type of logging?

Comment: Why don't you set your virtualhost config which includes the proxy directives first?

Comment: @priya-r I have the same problem. Where you able to log the response from upstream?

Comment: @solarc Nopes. But we fixed it by disabling keepalives. See: https://gunnarpeipman.com/iis/apache-iis-and-502-proxy-error/